# Every one verb agreement!

Tags: verbs, verb-agreement

How is try and why and what I can read to improve my understanding?

I write wrong the sentence - Every one of the clerks [were] given an increase in salary.

Now I know what try is the word [was] in the brackets above.

What book or site or page I shall read to improve my understanding of its case?

Comment: Hello Maxim, I guess English is not your native language? If so, you may find our [English learners site](https://ell.stackexchange.com) helpful.

Comment: The words *every*, *one*, *each*, and *everyone* (not all used here) take singular verbs. A good basic list can be found at [TERMIUM Plus](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_i&page=9A7V3j-fLVyE.html). This site's [meta site](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/) is used for reference material requests and suggestions,